# Generating number sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am doing this question from old exam paper to brush up on my ruby programming skills. I am having some problems with part 2. Seq_gen_b -> generate the sequence using **recursion**. Below is the question itself.

Basically it is asking to generate a sequence of numbers by taking in a value n, multiplying it by 2 and taking away 3. This new number is then used to generate the next number. These numbers are to be stored in an array. My issue is that I can't think of a good way to stop the recursion happening.

> Create two methods – seq_gen_a and seq_gen_b -- each of which will
>   take a number, n (which is > 2), and generate an array of four
>   elements, whose first element is n and next three elements are three
>   numbers in a sequence that doubles the previous number and takes 3
>   from it; such that, (i) seq_gen_a generates the sequence using
>   iteration, and (ii) seq_gen_b generates the sequence using recursion.
>   For example, given the number 5, both of these methods will output:
>   [5, 7, 11, 19] though, obviously, they will achieve this output in
>   different ways

This is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to stop it from just running out of memory. It maybe totally wrong

```
def seq_gen_b(n)
  if n < 2
     n
  else
   (0..2).each do |i|
    num = ((n * 2) -3)
   seq_gen_b(num)
   end
  end
end
```

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Why the rush in selecting an answer?

Comment: For `seq_gen_a`: `3.times.with_object([n]) { |_,a| a << a.last*2-3 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your method needs is an actual stop condition inside before making the recursive call:

```
def seq_gen_b(n)
  result = [n]
  seq_gen_b_helper(n, result, 3)
end

def seq_gen_b_helper(n, result, count)
  if count != 0
    value = ((n * 2) - 3)
    result << value
    seq_gen_b_helper(value, result, count - 1)
  else
    result
  end
end
```

Since you´re supposed to do 3 more objects, just use a simple counter to figure out if you are at the right count already and then return.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think that both of those designs are not very good. Generating the sequence, and choosing how many elements to take from it, are two very different concerns that shouldn't be mixed up in a single method.

For generating a sequence, Ruby already has the `Enumerator` class:

```
n = 5
e = Enumerator.new do |y| loop do y << n; n = 2*n - 3 end end
e.next # =>  5
e.next # =>  7
e.next # => 11
e.next # => 19
```

I would split the two different concerns into two different methods, one which returns the generator, and one which chooses how many elements to take. And `Enumerator` mixes in `Enumerable`, so we also have all of those methods available, including `take`. Which means that our method to choose how many elements to take has already been written for us. How nice! (That's what happens, when you use proper abstractions.)

```
def seq_gen(n) Enumerator.new do |y| loop do y << n; n = 2*n - 3 end end end

def seq_5_take_4; seq_gen(5).take(4) end

seq_5_take_4
# => [5, 7, 11, 19]
```

Comment: Jörg, I've recently faced so many idiots who don't get it how crucial separation of concerns is... I mean in computer science journals. Why is your answer not the accepted answer? Why don't they upvote you more?

Comment: Great food for thought! How about writing `def seq(first, size) Enumerator.new(&yield(first)).take(size) end`, here invoked `seq(5, 4) { |n| ->(y) { loop { y << n; n = 2*n - 3 } } } #=> [5, 7, 11, 19]`? Can this be written without putting a proc in a block?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is cleanest to use a single method, ideally using an optional parameter. My solution looks like:

```
def seq_gen_b(n, result=[])
  return result if result.count >=4
  result << n
  seq_gen_b((n*2)-3, result)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
def seq_gen_b(n, a=[*n])
  a.size==4 ? a : seq_gen_b(nil, a << a.last*2-3)
end

seq_gen_b(5)
  #=> [5, 7, 11, 19]
```

`[*n]` returns `n` if `n` is an array, `[n]` if `n` is an integer. `nil` is just a placeholder; any value will do.